# Phase term in Aharonov-Bohm effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, aharonov-bohm

In $U(1)$ gauge, the transformation is given by $(c=1)$ $$e^{\frac{ie\int A_\mu dx_\mu}{\hbar}}$$ I know that this form comes from the phase picked up by electrons in [Aharonov-Bohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) effect. However, in the magnetic Aharonov-Bohm effect, the form is connected with the existence of magnetic monopole. Such a monopole would restore a symmetry between the electric and magnetic sources in Maxwell's equations.

My question is if a monopole is never found, does that imply a modification in the phase term? What will be the consequence if the phase changes by a constant  factor independent of $$x_\mu?$$

Your comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is the other way around. If the condition $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec  B = 0$ does not hold then the vector potential cannot be defined. Indeed, $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec \nabla \times \vec  A = 0$ identically. Thus, if magnetic monopoles exist the expression must be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't Dirac argued the possibility of charge quantization, based on the existence of monopoles, given by $$\frac{\hbar}{e}$$? I think that factor is in the exponent.